# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '01:00' to data type int

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, insert

I don't know how to convert the nvarchar value into an int, but that is the way it needs to be set up. I've found other posts about this but I don't know how to use CAST in the INSERT statement I have. All the posts I could find were about converting to int in SELECT statements. I need this statement to change the field @Duration to an int in the database. @Duration is an amount of time. (01:00, 02:00...) They will all get rounded up to the next int value. So if a user enters 0:45, it should be converted to 1. Can someone help me figure out how to get this INSERT to work?

```
'SQL Insert: Product table
        Dim sqlInsertProduct As String = "INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, Status, 
                                         CreateDate, ModifyDate, CreateUser, 
                                         ModifyUser, Price, LaunchDate, Duration, 
                                         IsPublic, Presenter, Host, Broker) 

                                         VALUES (@ProductName, '1',getdate(),
                                         getdate(), @CreateUser, @ModifyUser,
                                         '0', @LaunchDate, @Duration, '1', 
                                         @Presenter, @Host, @Broker);
                                         SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlInsertProduct, cn)
            Dim ProductID As String
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProductName",
            txtNewWebinarName.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CreateUser",
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ModifyUser",
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LaunchDate", txtDateTime.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Duration", txtDuration.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Presenter", txtPresenter.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Host", txtHost.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Broker", txtBroker.Text))
            cn.Open()
            ProductID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            Session("ProductID") = ProductID
            Dim Product As String = Session("ProductID")
        End Using
        cn.Close()
```

Comment: and you want to convert that value to what int?? 1? 100? because that is not an int!

Comment: Assuming `txtDuration.Text` is a TimeSpan and you want to store it as hour,minute,second,millisecond or what?

Comment: Sorry, @Duration is an amount of time, say 01:00 that needs to be converted to a 1. 02:00 converted to 2, and so on.

Comment: I edited the original post. If a user enters a time like that it would need to be rounded up to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to convert a `TimeSpan` into an int, also assuming you want it's [TotalHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx) property:

```
Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(txtDuration.Text) 
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Duration", ts.TotalHours))
```

**Edit**: If this actually is a TimeSpan, your conversion would  be wrong, because the String "0:45" represents a TimeSpan of 0,75 hours(45 minutes are 3/4 hours).

This should do the rounding correctly:

```
Dim hours As Integer = _
       CInt(Math.Round(ts.TotalHours, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx

Comment: @jlg: Glad i could help. Edited my answer and added `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`, otherwise 0:30 would be 0 instead of 1.

Comment: One note: do you think it is user-friendly to let the use enter `0:31` and you store only 1(hour)?! That's an unnessecary loss of information, you could easily round it in the frontend but keep the precision and show it when needed.

Comment: No I don't. I was told to do it this way, so this is how it will be done unfortunately.

Comment: @jlg: Normally you would store a TimeSpan in SQL-Server as datetime object. Look here for more infos: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/01/02/56079.aspx Thats the most flexible way to store it without losing informations. It's part of the frontend to format/round the value e.g. to a quarter of an hour.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that. Since it's just a time, without a date, that we are using my boss said just to store it as a decimal. Apparently sql server has 'time' but I guess we only have 2005 so I can't use it. Not the best approach, but I'm not the boss. He likes to get it done fast and easy :(

Comment: Fast and easy can lead to (time)expensive and difficult if you plan to extend your functionality or store other timespans. It would be easy to write functions that convert the datetimes to durations (actually you could already use the functions linked in my last comment). A datetime in sql-server is  internally stored as two 4-byte integer. I don't see any disadvantages from storing a duration as datetime with basedate 1/1/1900.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll start updating my database. :)